# What's the best way to remove first div inside a parent div using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following markup:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="divToRemove">
    </div>
</div>
```

And I have the following jQuery to remove the first div which works fine:

```
$('#parent').find('div').remove();
```

Is this the best way to remove the first component?  Or is it more efficient to use selectors?  An example would be great!

**Please note**, I know I can use:

```
$('#divToRemove').remove();
```

however I'd like to be able to use selectors in this instance (reasons outside of scope of question).

Thanks,
Norm.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This should be the fastest and safest:

```
$('#parent').find('div').first().remove();
```

Answer (score 4):

You want

```
$('#parent').find('div:first').remove();
```

or it will remove all `<div>` within the parent `<div>`.

Answer (score 2):

let's say. you are doing JS event and you have access to "this"
I will do it this way.

```
$('#child').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('div#parent').children('div:first').remove();
});
```

clarify, this is not the most efficient way but useful in interactive event.
alternatively, you can make use of a few selector :

```
//closest,parent,next,prev,find,children and nth-child()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.  It work perfectly on me

$('#parent').find('div:first').remove();

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#parent').children('div:first').remove();
```

use this if you're only talking about removing immediate children div of parent. and it will be better than .find() when you have more inner divs.

Answer (score 0):

Ive got another one:

```
$('#parent > div:first').remove();
```

The '>' selects children of the element referenced to the left, and of course ':first" refers to the first child.